# Redux persist imports not importing

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Im following the documentation on the redux-persist github page but i dont know if they are for react native or not because im having issues with my imports. I am using Expo.

Heres what the documentation said you should use vs what i actually had to use:

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
    vs mine:
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/defaults/asyncLocalStorage'
```

The next one i need to import is this

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
```

However i cant figure out what file this is from at there is no 'integrations' folder.
Does anyone have any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that is not there? It is clearly part of the package as you can see here: https://unpkg.com/browse/redux-persist@6.0.0/integration/react/
Same for storage:
https://unpkg.com/browse/redux-persist@6.0.0/lib/storage/

Comment: I checked in the root nodules and they werent there, Can i ask you how you got that? It wouldve been helpful - I had to use a previous version to get it to work

Comment: The above links are to the package contents of redux-persist 6.0.0. You can view the contents of the exact package that is shipped by npm and installed in your node_modules folder on unpkg by opening https://unpkg.com/package-name in your browser.
Are you sure you were looking at the right module?

Comment: Thats weird. I must have done something wrong along the way to install the  wrong thing or something.It seems okay working on the older version anyway. Thanks for the help.